Keycloak - Get ClientCredentials access token with an "Authorization Scope"
I would like to create a basic ClientCredentials flow using keycloack with a specific scope associated with the resource server.

Creation of a Client called 'resource-server' with Authorization enabled.
In the Authorization section (Scopes subsection), creation of a scope "read".
Creation of a Client called 'client' with "Service accounts roles" enabled.
Http request :

curl --request POST   --url 'http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token'   --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'   --data grant_type=client_credentials   --data client_id=client --data client_secret=z1uSn57l7l4LLDayqybF7JM9zN3tP53l   --data scope=read

Response : {"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Invalid scopes: read"}
I expect a success from this request ! If I don't specify any scope, it works so it is definitely linked to the scope.
